# jOOQ table generation from existing class

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jooq

I need to create tables based on existing classes form the library using jOOQ. It's possible to use DB migration scripts (something like V1__first_script.sql) manually.

The question: is it possible to generate migration scripts or create tables by jOOQ exactly from the java class? Avoiding to write SQL scripts manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the [`DSLContext.ddl()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#ddl-org.jooq.Schema-) methods to generate a set of DDL queries from jOOQ generated code. Beware that this will not reproduce *all* of your schema definition, only the parts that the jOOQ API can represent. E.g. `CHECK` constraints are not yet included.